# Migrations not being applied to deployment for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to the deployment process for asp.net mvc apps. Everything runs and works great on the development machine but when i deploy it to IIS, i get an error about migrations. I have already ran the command update-database and PMC tells me that the database is up to date and there are no new migrations.
[image: Deployment Error]

Comment: The second line tells you the problem. The login it's using to try to access the database is incorrect.

Comment: why does it work on the dev machine? Im still connected to a db on a server. not the local machine.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to use integrated security. The user it's trying to log into needs to be authorized to access that database. Note that users with the same username on different domains aren't the same user. I would assume this user it's trying to use is different than the one you're using on your dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update-database manually, then make sure __EFMigrationHistory is behind the latest migrations you have in the queue,
OR in case of handling with code, you cand do as following in program.cs (.NET Core)

```
        var dbContext = provider.GetRequiredService<MMSDbContext>();
        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```